# Diplay Buttons/Elements 2 by 2 android (Listview ?)

Tags: android, listview, button, scroll

Hi i've a list of button like this :

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3
4. Item1
5. Item2

Each `Button` take 50% of the height, i want 2 of them **always** fully visible.

So far i put each button into a `ListView` and i dunno how to have a "fix" scroll that make them scroll 2 by 2. (some kind of magnetic scroll)

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrolling behavior you're describing (paging) is very similar to [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) in support library. The default `ViewPager` implementation however, supports horizontal paging only. So, you should be looking for a 'vertical viewpager'.

I found two libraries that provide such functionality, not sure about their state though:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/
https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/

You may have better luck searching for 'vertical viewpager' here or on github.

Comment: Well my ListView is actually inside a ViewPager.
So i don't want to go for a Vertical ViewPager inside a Horizontal Pager...

Comment: Why not? You already have a ListView inside a ViewPager, a vertical ViewPager inside a ViewPager shouldn't make the situation that different.

Comment: I'm in a situation a bit complicated with plenty of gesture : at the same time (more than only an horizontal ViewPager), the way ListView work right now fit perfectly. So i really want is to scroll them 2 by 2 .. like a VerticalPager

Comment: Then you will have to attach an OnScrollListener to the ListView, and scroll to the appropriate page in [onScroll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll). You will also have to dynamically set the item view height to be 50% of the ListView height. I would still vote for a vertical viewpager, after all, it's still the same gesture, and if a ListView is working fine, a ViewPager should work fine as well.